# How to create a copy/copied/duplicated form page in LibreOffice (for PDF form input)?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice-writer, forms

I created a LibreOffice Writer document including some **input forms**. How can I create a **copy page** where the **input-values are repeated** from the original page as copy for the person filling out the form?

Comment: What about duplicating the page? I am not sufficiently familiar with LibreOffice/OpenOffice Writer. If you can create a duplicate of a form field and get it out properly in the PDF, your input values are repeated, because both widgets (fields) would have the same field name. In PDF, the same field name also means the same value.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT the only way to do what I want at the moment (as suggested by @MaxWyss) is to:

Copy the whole page including the form elements and paste the content on a new page. By doing that the form control elements retain their original names (so there are at least two form elements with the same name/id).

If you then export to pdf including the checked option for "Allow[ing] duplicate field names" the fields with the same name/id can and will only contain the same content.